# How to reset/restart primary key in SQL Server in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL database in which there is table that suddenly got a huge jump in primary keys 5 -> 1005. Is there any way to reset PK back to eg. 6?

I have tried following:

```
USE [database name]
GO
ALTER SEQUENCE [schema name].[table name].[pk name]
    RESTART WITH 6
GO
```

But it returns error `'CREATE SEQUENCE' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.`

I have tried supposedly all the sensible variations of the query but without luck. Is there any other way to restart or reset the PK?

Comment: Caring about a gap in primary key values is indicative of a design flaw.

Comment: I agree but the cause was eventually SQL Server "feature": https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-2012-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing to understand is that the sequence does not belong to the table - it isn't part of it.  Don't specify the table, just the schema and sequence name.

```
USE [database name]
GO
ALTER SEQUENCE [Schema Name].[Sequence Name]
    RESTART WITH 6
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an [identity column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) you can use

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[schema_name].[table_name]', reseed, 0)
```

See the [documnetation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-resetting-the-identity-value-on-an-empty-table) for more info.